# How to get sp_track* from URI?

Tags: c++, spotify

there is a track uri like (spotify:track:14fmbvjYLqRZEXz1VZdM2M).
we want to find the sp_track* from the uri. But there is a problem that we can not know where it is from, maybe it is from a playlist, a search result, or some where else.

Currently I have 2 options:

(1). find the sp_track* in playlist to compare the uri one by one, if not found, continue to find it in the search result, if not found, ....

(2). uri => link => sp_track*

Which one is better, what's the difference of these 2 options. or do you have any other better solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is the better. Why do you have a problem with it ? Did you try it ?

Comment: Not only is the second solution better - it's the "correct" way of getting an `sp_track*` from a string URI.